# Install mysql-5.7 with ansible on ubuntu 14.04 trusty

Tags: mysql, ansible, ubuntu-14.04, apt, mysql-5.7

I'm trying to install Mysql-5.7 on ubuntu 14.04 which by default has no has no 5.7 package in its repositories.

So I try to add it manually with this little role:

```
---
- name: download the mysql deb package
  get_url: url=http://dev.mysql.com/get/{{ deb_filename }} dest=/tmp/{{ deb_filename }} mode=0644
  tags: apt

- name: install the package
  sudo: true
  apt: deb=/tmp/{{ deb_filename }}
  tags: apt

- name: update apt cache
  sudo: true
  apt: update_cache=yes
  tags: apt
```

Where deb_filename is the latest one “mysql-apt-config_0.8.7-1_all.deb”.

When I run a playbook with this role everything seems to run smoothly. No errors.

But then when it comes to a real installation of a package it says that:

> msg: No package matching 'mysql-client-5.7' is available

And when I login to the server and run “apt-cache search mysql-client” I see no mysql-5.7.

How can I add this package using ansible to my server?

Thanks everyone!

Comment: I've encountered the same issue. Did you find the solution?

Comment: You probably need to install `mysql-community-client` as the package name.